# Trying to build a calculator using Swift, basic operator buttons disappeared from main view controller, can't get it back

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm attempting the Swift beginner's project of building a calculator. I'm currently trying to add basic operators to the calculator.

[image]

However, I don't know what I have done, but suddenly, all the basic operators disappeared from the main vie controller

[image]

[image]

But the little + sign to the left of @IBAction func operator() still indicates the presence of basic operator, but it is no where to be found.

But when I run the program in Simulator, the basic operator reappears

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            enter()
        }
        switch operation {
        case "×":performOperation {$0 * $1}
        case "÷":performOperation {$1 / $0}
        case "+":performOperation {$0 + $1}
        case "−":performOperation {$1 - $0}
        case "√":performOperation {sqrt($0)}
        default: break
        }

    }

    func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double){
        if operandStack.count >= 2{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }

    private func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){
        if operandStack.count >= 1{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }

    var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    @IBAction func enter() {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)
        print("operantStack = \(operandStack)")
    }

    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those buttons are disabled for the current size class that you have selected. If you go over to the Utilities bar (on the right) and select the Attributes Tab (the one in the middle), scroll all the way to the bottom, make sure the first Installed box is checked for them. Have fun with the Stanford series.
[See attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kz7C.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! One little problem, could you please be a bit more specific, I'm not really sure what you meant by "first installed box". Thanks again for your help!

Comment: SS added. to answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It's finally back!! I'm so glad there are people like you out there helping out beginners like me!! Thanks again!

Comment: You're most welcome. This issue pops up with constrains and objects when you change the size class (bottom of the storyboard screen), and to best avoid it, do your work in the "Any, Any" size class whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

it's a constrain problem you are facing

just click on **Resolve Autolayout issue** under all view in container  -> **Click Update Frames and click update Constrain**

this will solve your issue

[image]

Comment: But those controls are greyed out, not just off screen.

Comment: @sschale can you upload your project so i can take look at it

Comment: I'm referring to OP's screenshot (3rd one), it's not my project.